# Build Failure with test cases using maven

Tags: xml, maven, junit, heap-memory

My project has some 40+ junit test cases and corresponding xml files.
When I try to build it using "mvn clean install" in the command prompt it fails. I have deleted a couple of test cases thinking there was a heap memory issue but it didn't help.

```
<error message="Unable to create application context for locations [com/infocast/context/mos/daoContextTest.xml, com/infocast/context/mos/default/daoContext.xml]" type="org.unitils.core.UnitilsException"><![CDATA[org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Unable to create application context for locations [com/infocast/context/mos/daoContextTest.xml, com/infocast/context/mos/default/daoContext.xml]
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:585)
    at net.sf.cglib.asm.Type.getDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.CodeEmitter.emit_field(CodeEmitter.java:468)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.CodeEmitter.getfield(CodeEmitter.java:425)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$3.processCase(Enhancer.java:740)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.CodeEmitter.process_switch(CodeEmitter.java:629)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.CodeEmitter.process_switch(CodeEmitter.java:602)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitGetCallback(Enhancer.java:738)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:509)
    at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:200)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
]]></error>
  </testcase>
```

Comment: Is there a problem when you run them normally?

Comment: we had surefire plugin in bas parent pom file which has less memory allocation. So i had to add this plugin in my pom file with more meomory

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue –
we had surefire plugin in bas parent pom file which has less memory allocation. So i had to add this plugin in my pom file with more memory

argLine-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -ea -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
under build >> plugin >> configuration >> argline